# Attaching Word Document as an Attachment - Path Specification ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mime, email-attachments

I need to attach a word document to an email.

The document is being stored in the solution, in a folder called "Attachments"

**Question**

I was wondering what path i need to use in order to attach a Word document to an email and also would like to know if I am attaching it correctly.

**Here is how I am doing it:**

```
string fileName = "~/Attachments/worddocument.doc";
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage
    {
        Sender = new MailAddress(this.SenderAddress, this.SenderName),
        From = new MailAddress(this.FromAddress, this.FromName),
        ReplyToList = { new MailAddress(this.ReplyToAddress, this.ReplyToName) },
        IsBodyHtml = this.isBodyHtml,
        Subject = this.UserSubject,
        Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet));
     };
```

How does that look? Did I specify the path correctly?

Thanks

Comment: How would we know? Does it work? And if not, what's the error?

Comment: I do not have data access right now so I cannot debug it right now. All I am asking is did I specify the path correctly. Simple question yet there are no examples that I could find on MSDN.

Comment: The only answer I have for you is: Maybe. This can be a legitimate path, but I have no idea if it's the right legitimate path.

Comment: You should read the question again. There is only one correct way to reference a folder in the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Attachment` expects an absolute path.

You can convert your virtual path to an absolute path with

```
var absolutePath = Server.MapPath("~/Attachments/worddocument.doc")
```

And attach it with

```
Attachments.Add(new Attachment(absolutePath, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet));
```

If you want to check if the file in the virtual directory exists, use

```
if (File.Exists(absolutePath))
...
```